# type of continuity in geo-statistics

Tags: spatial, geostatistics

I am reading the book by Wackernagel, H. (1995) Multivariate Geostatistics: An Introduction with Applications and on page 49 The fit is done by eye because it is generally not so relevant how well the variogram function fits the sequence of points. What counts is the **type of continuity** assumed for the regionalized variable and the stationarity hypothesis associated to the random function. These assumptions will guide the selection of an appropriate variogram function and this has many more implications than the way the theoretical function is fitted to the experimental variogram".

**SO I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW WHAT THE AUTHOR MEANS BY TYPE OF CONTINUITY**. IF YOU COULD ALSO GIVE MORE INSIGHT ON THIS STATEMENT I WOULD APPRECIATE A LOT.